# How to read the following code?

Tags: r

I have some difficulties to understand the structure of the following code.

I would say it takes the object b from data.frame data and outputes for every tuple of c and d the mean as well as sd(or outputes vector?). Am I wrong?

```
   A <- with(data ,
   tapply (b, list( c , d ),
   function (x) c(M = mean (x), SD = sd(x))))
```

According to the manuel tapply is used in respect to factors.If c & d were 1 & 0 would the command be still applicable? I´m not sure whether c & d were transformed to factors(yes & no) or whether the command was used on (1 & 0).

Comment: It depends on the context it's used in.  What is `data` defined as?

Comment: data is just a data frame containing a bunch of variables(numeric). But c & d are dummies

Comment: What do you mean, "dummies"? Do you just mean categorical coding variables?

Comment: Add result of `dput(head(data))` to your post.

Comment: Your explanation is correct. Of course, you could check this yourself easily.

Comment: I´m mean that c & d are binary variables. 1 & 0

Comment: @ Roland. Thx. But according to the manuel tapply is used in respect to factors. Do I miss something? If c & d  were integer would the command still applicable? The questin here is, I´m not sure whether c & were transformed to factors(yes&no) or whether the command was used on (1 & 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tapply` will coerce any of the list items to factor before doing the ragged table aggregation. Here is an example where the two columns given  to the INDEX argument are both integer:

```
set.seed(123); dff <- data.frame(N=rnorm(100), 
                          A=sample(0:1, 100, rep=TRUE), 
                          B=sample(0:1, 100, rep=TRUE) )

 tapply( dff$N, dff[2:3], mean)
   B
A            0          1
  0 -0.0120944 0.07484158
  1  0.1653022 0.16514699
```

Some people complain about the fairly widespread hidden coercion of values in R functions to other types. It's not a strongly typed language, but that does impose a burden on the user to understand the functions they are using.